# onActivityResult has data null for startActivityForResult in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment where I am calling `getActivity().startActivityForResult` for camera activity and I have `onActivityResult` in my `MainActivity` to handle the Result.

Fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 250);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 250);
try {
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   // Do nothing for now
}
```

MainActivity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) //CANCELED
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:


        Toast.makeText(this, "Pick from Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Result Okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                if (extras2 != null) {
                    //Doesn't enter here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "extra is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the host activity of fragment ?

Comment: Have you checked onActivityResult in fragment?

Comment: Log.wtf is much better for logging than Log.d - this is what i realized! use it, it only shows stuff you put in your logs - no system other logs will be shown!

Comment: @Shahzeb Yes But no luck. still the `data.getExtras()` is null

Comment: Check this example- http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-image-fragment-pager-view

Answer (score 1):

Activity @Oncreate open camera intent

```
// Camera Option Clicked    
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

Handle onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if (data != null) {

                takePhoto(data);
            }
        }

        break;
    }

}
```

Display image on ImageView

```
private void takePhoto(Intent imageData){
    Bundle extras = imageData.getExtras();

    if(extras != null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) extras.get("data"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

to

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

refer this for further information [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/6147919#6147919)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        112);
if (requestCode == 112) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(data.getData());
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    mFileTemp);
            copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);// do other stuff
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            //do other stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call
`startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);` from your fragment and then implement the  onActivityResult() in your Fragment itself, and in the onActivityResult() just check for the result code as

> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
>   if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {

Comment: still the `data.getExtras()` is null

Comment: how are you checking if the data.getExtras().? i do this   if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();if (extras != null) {BitmapDrawable cropped_image = extras.getParcelable("data");

Comment: did you read the question. All these were already done. I am getting null in `extras`